# RedHat/CentOS environment discovery

Tags: centos, redhat, samba, sunos

I am working with a new client who lost their IT person and are trying to document what they have. It's a Linux/SunOS environment.

I am trying to find their Samba or equivalent user management server but so far have been unable to do so.

From a client machine, Windows or Linux, what is the best way to go about locating this server?

Comment: nmap is your friend.

Comment: good idea. also found some pam files.

Comment: No _krb records in DNS? I'd start there, if something like IPA was in use. Might have some custom records for OpenLDAP too

Answer (score 0):

Use nmap and specify the ports to look for. A list of used port on samba is available [here](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_port_usage)

Answer (score 0):

history is also your best friend whenever you are going into a new environment.  I would do this first so you dont' lose anything

history > history.txt

On all machines so you can preserve everything previous root user did

Also 
netstat -lan

You can see what servers it is currently connecting to and on what ports.